# How to pass value from Javascript to td?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

My table like this :

```
<table>
    ...
        <tr>
            ...
            <td id="test"></td>
            ...
        </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

My jQuery like this :

```
$('#test').text() = 10;
```

I try like that, but it does not display anything

How can I display it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update content pass it as an argument to work [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2) method as a setter.

```
$('#test').text(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
$('#test').text()
```

That means you are trying to get the text of `td`. To set some string/html you can consider using `html()`

```
$('#test').html("10")
```

Setting `html()` works